# Unable to delete AWS EBS Volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, storage, block, volume

I created an EC2 instance with 2 EBS. 
I deleted that instance and now when I'm trying to delete these two volumes, I'm not able to do same, as it shows error as 'The volume ---- doesn't exist'.

[image: ErrorScreenshot]

But it is clearly showing up in volume list.

Answer (score 0):

By default EBS root volumes are deleted and non-root volumes are kept (except if "delete on terminate" is checked for any of the volumes).

If "delete on terminate" were set to the volume you are trying to delete or this volume was supposed to be deleted by default, then you might be experiencing an error due to the UI not being updated reflecting the previous deletion of the volume.

Comment: Volumes **may be** deleted when the instance is terminated. It purely depends on the "delete on terminate" flag of the volume attachment. However, 100% correct about the UI not being updated yet.

Comment: You are right. Just updated the answer to reflect your point.

Comment: Even root volumes obey "delete on terminate". In this regard, root or non-root does not matter.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It helped me.